# Get posts from page that hasn't setup a custom alias?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm visiting a number of Facebook pages and collecting information about their posts. When the Facebook page has created a custom username / alias, I can simply query their page like so, using their ID:

```
$accessToken = FACEBOOK_APP_ID.'|'.FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET;
$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/104958162837/?access_token=' . $accessToken;
```

However, if they didn't bother to setup a custom username / alias, then it won't work, even if I specify:

- The default alias that FB gave them when they created the page (looks something like **My-Page-Name-104958162837**).
- The numerical ID of their page.

What gives?

Comment: do you have an example page/link? which token are you using? app token? user token?

Comment: I've updated the question to include how I create my token. Also, an example would be: https://www.facebook.com/The-Stores-Wexford-129319107123637/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine for me that way, if use a User Token:

`/129319107123637`

`/129319107123637/feed`

Just try it in the API Explorer, after authorization: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895?method=GET&path=129319107123637&version=v2.5

It only does not work with an App Token if the Page is restricted by age or location. In that case, you have to use a User Token of a User who is allowed to see the Page, of course.

Comment: It does actually work. I am clearly doing something very stupid here.

Comment: it is not THAT stupid ;) - you just have to realize how tokens work. an app token does not have any user relation, so facebook does not know if the user is allowed to see the page, that is all.

Comment: Actually, scrap that. I think you're right here. I can't view the page if I'm not logged in!